# Get all subdirectories that match pattern

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm using Python 3.7.7.

I have this code that get all the subdirectories:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Get all subdirectories.
p = Path(root_path)
dir_lst = [str(x) for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir()]
```

But now I need to get all  the subdirectories which name starts with a pattern like `Challen_2013*`.

How can I do it?

Comment: `[str(x) for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir() and x.name.startswith("Challen_2013")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glob` as in the previous answer, or just use `startswith` to filter the results:

```
[str(x) for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir() if x.name.startswith("Challen_2013")]
```

Comment: can be replace str(x) to x.as_posix(): [x.as_posix() for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir() if x.name.startswith("Challen_2013")]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use glob:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob(f"root_path/{Challen_2013*}")
for file in files:
# do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit dirty, but simple

`[str(x) for x in p.iterdir() if x.is_dir() and str(x).startswith('Challen_2013')]`

Comment: That's the answer bigbounty posted as a comment and it isn't working since the string does not start with that substring. It's a subdirectory. The string starts with the root path. quickedit: Comment was edited. It works with `x.name.startswith()`. But `str(x).startswith()` is still a wrong answer.